# How to disable proceed to checkout button when enter invalid post code in Magento2.1?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

We need to disable '**Proceed to Checkout**' button on the cart page, When user enter invalid postal/zip-code using custom module.

Please help to find a solution.